# PHP or JavaScript or jQuery cookie expire 5 minutes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies, setcookie

How would I use PHP to set a cookie to expire in 5 minutes?
I'm familar with `setcookie()`, but not with it's time property. An explanation would be nice.

Can somebody please point me to the right direction (or include a sample code)?

Thanks a lot. :)

(P.S. I woudn't mind a solution in jQuery or in JavaScript either.)

Comment: You might want to read the documentation for **[`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)** before posting. In the **expire** parameter it cleary exemplifies what you need to input for 30 days, which is [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)`+60*60*24*30`. Then it's basic arithmetic calculation.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php <--- all your answers

Comment: Watch my reputation falll...... along with the downvotes. I think some people find it fun, like a game! (sometimes I feel sour, hope you understand. :))

Comment: We all are more than willing to help each other here but we also expect to see some effort and research before someone is posting a question.

Comment: I didn't undertand the stuff about the `time()` in the manuel, guess if someone is dumb they just shouldn't ask... :( Sorry, I'm worried that the same thing that happened in my other account (I got banned from asking questions)... http://stackoverflow.com/users/752723/dumb-search . Sorry, I just guess I shoudn't be a help vampire. I try not to be one... :{

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the downvotes, we all get some of them even when they don't make any sense (and no, it wasn't me). That's how SO works. Anyway you don't need to understand the `time()` function. Just use it like in the example because it returns the current time whatever it is at that moment. So that moment + 5 minutes will always be 5 minutes from now for anybody. As with `60*60*24*30` it is `60secs*60mins*24hrs*30days`.

Comment: @inhan aw thanks yur nice.:) and thanks for the explanation of setcookie

Answer (score 3):

`setcookie()` set the expire to time() + (60 * 5) 60 = seconds. 5 = how many minutes.

```
setcookie($name, $value, time() + (60 * 5), $path, $domain)
```

Comment: So `setcookie()`'s `time()` goes by milliseconds?

Comment: `number of seconds since the epoch` VIA http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php time() = seconds since epoch

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22651/discussion-between-class-and-solene-le-van)